# How to select parts of string in MySQL 5.x

Tags: mysql

I have a varchar(255) field within a source table and the following contents:

```
50339  My great example
2020002  Next ID but different title
202020  Here we go
```

Now I am processing the data and do an insert select query on it. From this field I would need the INT number at the beginning of the field. IT IS followed by 2 spaces and a text with var length, this text is what I need as well but for another field. In General I want to to put text and ID in two fields which are now in one.

I tried to grab it like this:

```
SELECT STATUS REGEXP '^(/d{6,8})  ' FROM products_test WHERE STATUS is not null
```

But then I learned that in MySQL 5.x there are no regexp within the SELECT statement.

How could I seperate those values within a single select statment, so I can use it in my INSERT SELECT?

---

From the correct solution of user slaakso, resulted another related problem since somtimes the STATUS field is empty which then results in only one insert, but in case there is a value I split it into two fields. So the count does not match. 
My case statement with his solution somehow contains a syntax problem:

```
CASE STATUS WHEN '' 
THEN( 
    NULL, 
    NULL
) 
ELSE( 
    cast(STATUS as unsigned), 
    substring(STATUS, locate(' ', STATUS)+3) 
) 
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do following. Note that you need to treat the columns separately:

```
select 
  if(ifnull(status, '')!='', cast(status as unsigned), null),
  if(ifnull(status, '')!='', substring(status, locate('  ', status)+2), null)
from products_test;
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fxnSmFaAkjL4aD2s51sZw9/2)

Comment: That is a great statement! Thank you, I learned quite a bit from it.
My case is a bit different, sometimes the field is empty. So I have to assigne NULL to both fields. With one field it worked, but with two I might have a syntax problem in my statement now:      
    CASE STATUS WHEN '' THEN(
            NULL,
            NULL
        )
        ELSE(
            cast(STATUS as unsigned),
            substring(STATUS, locate('   ', STATUS)+3)
        )
    END,

Comment: @slaasko I updated the question to illustrate the case better formated.